# Flink checkpoint restore time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to calculate the checkpoint restore time in Flink stateful stream processing. If we have any metric in Flink to check it as I could not find on the dashboard. If it is not available, then how can we achieve it?

thanks

Comment: There is a checkpoint tab in the job dashboard.

Comment: It does not give restore time.